# Is there a way I can import ReadItLater's exported html file into my Instapaper?

Tags: html, instapaper, pocket

Is there a way I can import my ReadItLater's exported html file into my Instapaper?

Comment: Are you exporting one article or a raft of them in one file?

Comment: It's one exported html file acquired via the complementary export feature at Read It Later, but I have around 1500 entries in my Read It Later list. Now that Instapaper has search too, I would prefer to use Instapaper for many reasons.

Comment: Since instapaper doesn't crawl a list of links on the server side, but expects the text to be downloaded by another app, and it saves the text you see, is not a good fit for importing a HTML dump. you'll need to find or craft a tool to iterate over the list and upload that data to your instapaper account. Hopefully someone know of or makes that tool and replies since both are popular tools.

Comment: Would you mind up-voting my question then to help out please? Thanks.

Comment: Sure - there needs to be an app for that. From the remarks I've seen - marco doesn't intend his service to hold everything - just a curated list of carefully added links.  Bulk import isn't likely what he's shooting for. Until you find an app - look to pinboard.in http://pinboard.in/upgrade/ at $25 a year. Maciej has written your app - just he stores the text on his server - not instapaper's. I use both and am most happy with the combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Though I don't have a tool now, I guess it can be done in couple of ways. Yes, no one click solution.</strike>

1. Email each url to your personal instapaper id ([Refer this Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5493449/instapaper-adds-email-functionality-for-easy-article-saving))
2. Can parse your export list and use simple API from Instapaper to add the links to your account. [Refer API docs](http://www.instapaper.com/api/simple)

**Update**:

As I said earlier, it is not a one click solution but doable. As a matter of fact, I did create an extension for chrome to do this. Here is the link http://minus.com/mc3va2C

**Update 2**:

The source of the extension is available @ https://github.com/palaniraja/RIL2Insta

Comment: This isn't an answer to what @HandyRandy was asking at all.

Comment: Love to hear feedback from you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get that statement.

Comment: @odiniulf I've updated my answer. It is just a beta version. It would be great if you can test and give feedback

Comment: Sorry, I've been away from Mac. I will give this a test. Sounds great, thanks. I'll report back soon.

Comment: I'll be damned! It work very well :) Many thanks to you Palaniraja! Out of 1636 entries, only 2 failures. And I have a feeling they're probably false errors anyway (just a hunch). As for feedback on user experience, I'd suggest adding an explanation on how to get the source code of the .html RIL file for the novices. Also, the success/failure report is a nice touch which I appreciated :)

Comment: happy to hear that. I'll be doing one to import instapaper  export.html to Read It Later to counter this. Will publish the source soon. Btw, would you mind awarding me the bounty? :)

Comment: Oh sure! I was assuming accepting your answer would've done that. It's my first bounty. Publishing the source is a good idea. Some folks will be hesitant to enter their credentials if not.

Comment: Just so you know, I believe RIL already supports the importing of Instapaper's .html file. See here - http://readitlaterlist.com/import/instapaper/

Comment: BTW, I think you should email Marco Arment [Instapaper Dev] and see if he'll add this to Instapaper.com somewhere. At the very least, I'll bet he'll tweet it or post it on his blog :)

Comment: @HandyRandy Yeah, just mailed him. Will publish source tonight.

Comment: The link in Update 1 is no longer online =(

Answer (score -3):

No, there is no way of doing this. *With those applications.*